# ¿Como usar el option value en php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un menú desplegable, con 2 opciones:

Nuevo cliente y Nuevo producto.

Lo que busco es que al tener seleccionada determinada opción me lleve a un formulario distinto, en caso de que seleccione "Nuevo Producto" que me lleve a un formulario donde agrego esta información.

El problema es que no recuerdo el código con el que se hacia esto...

Codigo del menu:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" onSubmit="return validar();">
  <p>
    <label for="select"></label>
    <select name="menu" id="menu">
      <option value="nc">Nuevo Cliente</option>
      <option value="np">Nuevo Producto</option>
    </select>
     <input type ="submit" value ="Registrar" />
</form>
```

Valido que opción esta seleccionada con javascript, pero no recuerdo como iniciar otro formulario dependiendo de la opción seleccionada.

```
<script>
  function validar(valor) {
    if (menu.value == "nc") {
      // Quiero saber el código para cambiar de formulario
      // en caso de que seleccione esta opción
    }   
    if (menu.value == "np") {
      // Quiero saber el código para cambiar de formulario
      // en caso de que seleccione esta opción
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Lo queres hacer de forma dinamica o que se recargue la pagina?

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que al seleccionar por ejemplo "Nuevo Producto" me lleve a otro formulario, es decir, que me lleve a "nuevoproducto.php"

Comment: hay mas datos para enviar en el formulario? o es solo cambiar de url según la opcion?

Comment: Solo cambiar de Url segun la opcion

Comment: Pues lo que tenes que hacer en este caso es dentro del if, colocar un location.href = "nuevoproducto.php";

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script>
 function validar(valor) {
   if (menu.value == "nc") {
    location.href = "nuevoproducto.php";
   } else if (menu.value == "np") {  
    location.href = "nuevocliente.php";
   }
}
</script>

<form name="form1" method="post" onSubmit="return validar(this);">
  <p>
    <label for="select"></label>
    <select name="menu" id="menu">
      <option value="nc">Nuevo Cliente</option>
      <option value="np">Nuevo Producto</option>
    </select>
    <input type ="submit" value ="Registrar" />
</form>
```

De esta forma lo puedes hacer, si lo que quieres es que según la opción mande a un formulario u otro.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta asignandole el evento `onchange` al `select`, enviandole la referencia del select con `this`. Luego verificas que valor fue seleccionada utilizando el la propiedad `value`:

```js
function redireccionar(select){
  if(select.value == "nc") {
    console.log("redireccionar a nc");
  } else if(select.value == "np"){
    console.log("redireccionar a np");
  } else{
    console.log("ninguna opcion valida seleccionada");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" onSubmit="return validar();">
  <p>
    <label for="select"></label>
    <select name="menu" id="menu" onchange="redireccionar(this)">
      <option value="nc">Nuevo Cliente</option>
      <option value="np">Nuevo Producto</option>
    </select>
     <input type ="submit" value ="Registrar" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer de diferentes maneras, te dejo una utilizando [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // capturo el evento cada vez que cambia el selector
  $('#menu').on('change', function() {
    // obtengo el valor
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    // si es np cambio el action del form por nuevoproducto
    if (value == 'np') {
      $('#form1').attr('action', 'nuevoproducto.php');
    }
    // si es nc cambio el action del form por nuevocliente
    else if (value == 'nc') {
      $('#form1').attr('action', 'nuevocliente.php');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="select"></label>
    <select name="menu" id="menu">
      <option value="nc">Nuevo Cliente</option>
      <option value="np">Nuevo Producto</option>
    </select>
     <input type ="submit" value ="Registrar" />
</form>
```

Entonces cada vez que cambies el combo, va a enviar el formulario a un archivo u otro dependiendo de lo que selecciones.

Comment: El necesita redireccionar a otra pagina, según sea la opción del select. No cambiar el action.